Flowgear Data Transformation. I want to get more information on how to transform the data
Suppose, I have the input as follows:
[
  { "name": "Archer" },
  { "name": "Cyril"  },
  { "name": "Pam"    }
]

and I want to get the output as
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Archer" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Cyril"  },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Pam"    }
]

We can do this using for each node to loop through all the objects, what if I have a long script and I need to use various for each nodes. In such case, it is not feasible. Is there a function like map function in javascript.
Thanks,

The best node for such operations would be the Quickmap node, but the method to achieve this would depend on what you are trying to achieve with the incrementing IDs in your target json body.
If you want to count from 1 for every element in your array, then you can try the following.
You would need additional nesting for your source payload so that we can use the INDEXOF() function to index each element we have in the array as shown below:
First I am adding the nesting as mentioned. I am passing your original body from this post into the Body property on the Formatter node and the Result of the Formatter is being passed into the Source of the Quickmap node.


I have copied my Result from the Formatter Node and then I added an id field to each element and pasted it into the Target payload in the Quickmap node. The Quickmap mapping would look like this:

Above you will see I mapped the second container from Source to the id field of my Target and then I used the INDEXOF() function to index each element in the id field. I also added a "+1" to the mapping expression so that it can start from 1.
From here you can use a Script node with some C# to get rid of the extra nesting we needed.
If you need your IDs to remember what the last ID was and you need it to index from where the last instance of the Workflow left off, I would suggest you use Flowgear Key Values to keep track of the last ID.
In this example, I used the same workflow as above and modified it to save the max ID of the last execution of the Workflow.
I now have a Get Key Value node at the start of my workflow and a Set Key Value node at the end. Here I needed to create a Group to keep track of the Key Values as well as a Key. The Group is coming from a Variable Bar and the Key is hardcoded on the Get and Set Key Values node (Shown in red in the screenshot). You can decide where these should come from.

When this example workflow runs for the first time, we would not have any Key Values set, so that is why I hooked up the Missing property of the Get Key Value node to a placeholder Formatter node that just holds a hardcoded 0 for the first run that will be passed into the Quickmap node. After it runs once, it will set the ID to the max ID from my Quickmap into the Key value storage to be accessed in future runs.
For the future runs, the workflow will go into the Found property and this can be passed into the Quickmap property to be accessed with GETVALUE() so that we can interact with values from outside the Quickmap node. I called mine LastId. I also added a CurrentMaxId field to my Result payload, just under the Root container.

The Quickmap mappings can then be changed as shown below:

Once this is done on the Quickmap, you can pass CurrentMaxId into Value on your Set Key Values node so that this can be set for the next run.
